# Spring Boot actuator trigger method when endpoint called

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am using this spring boot actuator endpoint "actuator/health/readiness". How can I run some methods when this endpoint is hit?

If I create my own controller with the same endpoint naming what will happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Works in spring 2.7.2

```
public class CustomReadinessStateHealthIndicator extends ReadinessStateHealthIndicator {

    public CustomReadinessStateHealthIndicator(ApplicationAvailability availability) {
        super(availability);
    }

    @Override
    public Health getHealth(boolean includeDetails) {
        //YOUR CODE
        return super.getHealth(includeDetails);
    }
}
```

```
@AutoConfiguration(before = {AvailabilityHealthContributorAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Configuration {

    @Bean("readinessStateHealthIndicator")
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "readinessStateHealthIndicator")
    public ReadinessStateHealthIndicator customReadiness(ApplicationAvailability applicationAvailability) {
        return new CustomReadinessStateHealthIndicator(applicationAvailability);
    }
}
```

Comment: OK will test this and report back, exactly what I wanted

Comment: Can you explain why the configuration class is needed? @viking

Comment: Because spring first looks up configuration class and then others class of bean annotated by `@Component` etc. So we need looks up first `CustomReadinessStateHealthIndicator` and for sure `before = {AvailabilityHealthContributorAutoConfiguration.class}` because AvailabilityHealthContributorAutoConfiguration make main bean of this type Indicator.

Comment: In my case the AutoConfiguration had to be replaced with Configuration to be able to make it work. Great solution otherwise!